# Remove bindings using SPWebConfigModification

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, spwebconfigmodification

I am dynamically adding bindings in `web.config`. But I don't know how to remove it

Here is complete code

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;

        webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

        string endpointadr = "https://testserver/myservice.svc"


        string bindings = @"
                            <bindings>
                              <wsHttpBinding>        
                                <binding name=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"">
                                  <security mode=""TransportWithMessageCredential"">
                                    <transport clientCredentialType=""None"" />
                                    <message clientCredentialType=""UserName"" establishSecurityContext=""false"" />
                                  </security>
                                </binding>
                              </wsHttpBinding>
                            </bindings>
                            <client>      
                            <endpoint address="""+endpointadr+ @""" binding=""wsHttpBinding"" bindingConfiguration=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService""
                            contract=""testService.IMyService"" name=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"" />
                            </client>";


        webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        RemoveModifications();
        webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(AddBindings(bindings));

        webApp.Update();
        webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();


    }



    private SPWebConfigModification AddBindings(string bindingString)
    {
        var modification = new SPWebConfigModification("bindings", "configuration/system.serviceModel");
        modification.Value = bindingString;
        //modification.Sequence = 0;
        modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
        modification.Owner = Owner;
        return modification;
    }

    private string Owner
    {
        get { return "MyTestPage" + webApp.Id; }
    }

    private void RemoveModifications()
    {
        var mods = from m in webApp.WebConfigModifications.AsEnumerable() where m.Owner == Owner select m;

        while (mods.Count() != 0)
        {
            webApp.WebConfigModifications.Remove(mods.First());
        }
    }
```

It's not removing anything when I call `removeModification`

**Update 1**
In web.config its adding like this

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://testserver/myservice.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" contract="Myservice.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" />
</client>
                            <bindings>
                              <wsHttpBinding>        
                                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService">
                                  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                                  </security>
                                </binding>
                              </wsHttpBinding>
                            </bindings>
                            <client>      
                            <endpoint address="https://testserver/myservice.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" contract="MyService.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" />
                            </client>
```

Not sure why its adding client tag twice

Answer (score 0):

You should change your approach as below

```
SPWebConfigModification entry = new SPWebConfigModification();
entry.Path = "configuration";
entry.Name = "bindings";
entry.Sequence = 0;
entry.Owner = "YourFeatureName";
entry.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
entry.Value =  @"<bindings>
                          <wsHttpBinding>        
                            <binding name=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"">
                              <security mode=""TransportWithMessageCredential"">
                                <transport clientCredentialType=""None"" />
                                <message clientCredentialType=""UserName"" establishSecurityContext=""false"" />
                              </security>
                            </binding>
                          </wsHttpBinding>
                        </bindings>
                        <client>      
                        <endpoint address="""+endpointadr+ @""" binding=""wsHttpBinding"" bindingConfiguration=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService""
                        contract=""testService.IMyService"" name=""WSHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService"" />
                        </client>";
webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Add (entry);
```

Now for removing you can use

```
Collection<SPWebConfigModification> allModifications = webApplication.WebConfigModifications;
int initialCount = allModifications.Count;
for (int i = initialCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    SPWebConfigModification Testmodification = allModifications [i];
    if (Testmodification.Owner == "YourFeatureName")
        allModifications.Remove(Testmodification);
}
if (initialCount > allModifications.Count)
{
    webApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();                
    webApplication.Update();
}
```

Comment: i get error on webApplication.count .. cannot resolve symbol count

Comment: Sorry it should be `int initialCount = allModifications.Count;`

Comment: Doesnt remove anything

Comment: Can you try debugging and see code is getting executed and the `if` condition is met.

Comment: I have not included entry.Sequence = 0; in my code because if i do then it removed this <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> under system.serviceModel

Comment: Its adding client tag twice. Please check updated question

Comment: I have debugged and not getting any error. Infact it adds client tag twice when i try to remove. What could be reason